# Need assistance on for loop example, I don't know how it works

Tags: java

Can anyone help me understand how this equals to 400? I can't figure it out how the `for` works.

```
import java.util.*; //for class Scanner
public class Exercise 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

   int value =0;
   for (int num = 10; num<= 40; num +=2){
       value =value+num;
   }
   System.out.println(value); 
}
```

Comment: tell us what you think so we can clarify your thoughts for you. tell us how much you understand this

Comment: the for increments the 10 by 2, so it is 10, 12, 14, 16, ...., 40, then  the num + value, that what it does

Comment: get a piece of paper and pen, write it down. show us why it shouldn't be 400

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably easiest to understand if you look at the actual values that will be used when the loop is evaluated. Given that `num` is initialized to **10**, and the loop will end when it equals or exceeds **40**, these are the 16 iterations the loop goes through:

```
value = value + num
-------------------
value = 0     + 10
value = 10    + 12
value = 22    + 14
value = 36    + 16
value = 52    + 18
value = 70    + 20
value = 90    + 22
value = 112   + 24
value = 136   + 26
value = 162   + 28
value = 190   + 30
value = 220   + 32
value = 252   + 34
value = 286   + 36
value = 322   + 38
value = 360   + 40
```

The final value of `value` being 400.

Answer (score 5):

A Java `for` loop is an example of a [Traditional `for` loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#Traditional_for_loops), from the linked Wikipedia page,

```
for(INITIALIZATION; CONDITION; INCREMENT/DECREMENT){
  // Code for the for loop's body
  // goes here.
}
```

So, your posted example is equivalent to

```
int value = 0;
int num = 10;
while (num <= 40) {
  value += num;
  num += 2;
}
System.out.println(value);
```

Of course, you could simply add output to see it in action with,

```
for (int num = 10; num <= 40; num += 2) {
    System.out.printf("value = %d, num = %d%n", value, num);
    value = value + num;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first pass

```
value = value + num;
  10   =   0 +    10;
```

second pass:

```
value = value + num;
 22  =  10   +     12
```

third pass:

```
 value = value + num;
  36         22  +  14
```

in a for loop

```
for(initializer, condition, increment){

   do something!

}
```

initializer is the beginning number

condition is what will cause the loop to stop

increment is how much you want to add to the initializer in order to meet the condition at the correct time.